# Generator does not seem to expose `resume()` method

Tags: rust, generator, resume

I was having a look at [generators in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/generators.html), and decided to give it a try. I implemented the most basic example I could come find:

```
#![feature(generators, generator_trait)]

use std::ops::Generator;

fn main() {
    let mut generator = || {
        println!("2");
        yield;
        println!("4");
    };

    println!("1");
    generator.resume();
    println!("3");
    generator.resume();
    println!("5");
}
```

However, when I try to compile I get this error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `resume` found for type `[generator@src/main.rs:6:25: 10:6 _]` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:13:15
   |
13 |     generator.resume();
   |               ^^^^^^
```

Am I doing something wrong or the `resume()` method actually does not exist on generators? If so, how can I wake up a generator? The documentation I could find all points to the `resume()` method, so I am confused now.

**Note**: Yes, I am aware that this is an unstable feature of the language, but on the doc it does encourage users to try and use it, so I am assuming it should be at least partially implemented?

**My current environment**: `rustc 1.35.0-nightly (acd8dd6a5 2019-04-05)`

Comment: your own link show you the answer

Comment: Well I must have gone blind! Sorry for the waste of time!

Comment: not really, this could be useful for future reader but it's just strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes, I am aware that this is an unstable feature

Unstable features tend to change over time and this is the case. With the recent stabilization of `Pin` the signature of [`resume`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.Generator.html#tymethod.resume) has been changed ([PR #55704](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/55704))

```
fn resume(self: Pin<&mut Self>) -> GeneratorState<Self::Yield, Self::Return>;
```

But fortunately the examples has also [been adopted](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.Generator.html).

So your code needs to look like this:

```rust
#![feature(generators, generator_trait)]

use std::ops::Generator;
use std::pin::Pin;

fn main() {
    let mut generator = || {
        println!("2");
        yield;
        println!("4");
    };

    let mut pin = Pin::new(&mut generator);
    println!("1");
    pin.as_mut().resume();
    println!("3");
    pin.as_mut().resume();
    println!("5");
}
```

The upside of this is, that this approach does not need `unsafe` anymore (which your code is missing and therefore should not compile on an older nightly) and that's why the `Pin` API has been choosen for the generator.

Lessons learned: If you are using the nightly compiler, also use the [nightly doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/).

Comment: new API doesn't look very user friendly.

Comment: To be closer to the original code, you can omit the state check: `Pin::new(&mut generator).resume();`

Comment: @Stargateur better?

Comment: @Stargateur that's because generators are pretty low level. However, like futures (which are built on generators), most people won't use this syntax. There's a closure-like syntax that will be used instead.